# Displaying my program using a projector, but hiding the input window

Tags: qt, output, projector

I'd like to create a darts-scoring-program using Qt, which has a window for the data input like thrown points, players name,... on my PC screen. The results should be shown as output on a projector or second screen. I don't get how to just display the output surface, so the guests watching the game don't see my input window. Is this a problem of programming, or do I have to adjust my settings (sources, from where my projector gets the information for example)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Make sure that the projector is configured as a separate display, not as a mirror of the primary display. That's to be done using system settings on your PC. Partition your application into two windows. You can then manually (with mouse or touch input) move one of the windows to the projector screen. Once you got that working, you can figure out how to do it programmatically: Qt provides you full screen geometry information needed for that.

Comment: Uhm, indeed that's a simple solution I never thought about, thanks ;)